# When to CREATE TABLE AS SELECT versus CREATE TABLE LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, create-table

I can "copy" a table using:
`CREATE TABLE copy LIKE original_table`
and
`CREATE TABLE copy as select * from original_table`

In the latter case only the data are copied but not e.g primary keys etc.
So I was wondering when would I prefer using a `select as`?

Answer (score 5):

These do different things.  `CREATE TABLE LIKE` creates an *empty* table with the same structure as the original table.

`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` inserts the data into the new table.  The resulting table is not empty.  In addition, `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` is often used with more complicated queries, to generate temporary tables.  There is no "original" table in this case.  The results of the query are just captured as a table.

EDIT:

The "standard" way to do backup is to use . . . . `backup` at the database level.  This backs up all objects in the database.  Backing up multiple tables is important, for instance, to maintain relational integrity among the objects.

If you just want a real copy of a table, first do a `create table like` and then `insert into`.  However, this can pose a challenge with `auto_increment` fields.  You will probably want to drop the `auto_increment` property on the column so you can populate such columns.

Comment: So what is the standard way to create a backup-copy of a table?

Answer (score 2):

The second form is often used when the new table is not an exact copy of the old table, but contains only selected columns or columns that result from a join.

Answer (score 2):

"Create Table as Select..." are most likely used when you have complex select

e.g:

```
create table t2 as select * from t1 where x1=7 and y1 <>2 from  t1;
```

Now, apparently you should use Create Like if you don't need such complex selects. You can change the PI in this syntax also.